# Is <algorithm> supposed to include AES intrinsics on x86 and x64?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, x86, intrinsics

I added `<algorithm>` to a standard header file that's included with most files in my project. Adding the file broke a compile on Debian 8.2/amd64 when using `-std=c++11`. I know why things broke, so I'm not interested in opinions on it.

I'm interested in two pieces of information. The questions are:

- ***What is supposed to be included in `<algorithm>`?***
- ***Is `<algorithm>` supposed to include AES intrinsics on x86 and x64?***

Comment: Wait, so you defined your own intrinsics in "cpu.h"? `_anything` is reserved in the global namespace, so it's perfectly valid for the library to use that name.

Comment: All identifiers that contain a double underscore are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: From the question you linked: "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace." The two cases you list (double underscore and `_Capital`) are reserved everywhere, not just in the global namespace.

Comment: Use the "search" function on your browser. I literally copy-pasted the quote. If you prefer a more recent vintage of the working draft, then http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3, bullet 2.

Comment: This is not a regression. This is you were lucky getting away with undefined behaviour and your luck just has ran out. *Anything* reserved for the implementation *can* be in *any* file you include. You are not supposed to touch any of this stuff. That's why it's called "reserved for the implementation".

Comment: "we provide the implementation" --- of what? C++? OS?

Comment: Do you understand what "reserved for the implementation" means? "Implementation" is a "C++ implementation" here, that is, the compiler. Intel provides those with their compiler. They ship a compiler, these names are reserved for the compiler, so they can do that. GCC does exactly the same.

Comment: I don't think you understand what "reserved for the implementation" means. Perhaps you should ask a question about this term here.

Comment: @n.m. - I reworked the question. It appears the additional context information was distracting too many readers.

Comment: Once again: there is an infinite set of identifiers that the C++ standard specifically reserfes for the use of the implementation or the standard libraries. Any of those may be defined in any standard library header, or predefined by the compiler as a keyword, or otherwise be unavailable to user programs.

Comment: @n.m. - Once again: what does this have to do with the question that was asked? Can I not use `std::sort` on any conforming implementation of the C++ standard library?

Comment: Your question is now too vague and broad so it is impossible to answer without knowing the context. I would vote to close it if I weren't involved in it already. There is enough information in the comments to answer your question, repeated several times. I won't try to repeat it any more.

Comment: @n.m. - *"Your question is now too vague and broad to answer..."* - I doubt it. I would wager the C++ standard calls out a set of classes or interfaces that should be present in that header. Perhaps you should edit the question to the question you are trying to answer....

Comment: The standard sets up requirerments on implementations. These requirements specify, among other stuff, a finite set of identifiers that each header must define, together with their meaning. It also specifies an infinite set of identifiers that an implementation is free to use for its own needs. Portable user programs cannot use those. These are *reserved to the implementation*. Some of them are listed in 17.6.4.3.2 "Global names". If you have an issue with this notion, why not ask a question that mentions it by name?